# CSS Properties and Style Manager in Visual Studio 2013 not working

Tags: css, visual-studio-2012

So I'm watching an online course for Visual Studio, and right now I'm working with some simple CSS. However, while the tutorial uses CSS Properties and Style Manager to simplify the styling, neither of them works for me. If I open styles.css or any .aspx page using the stylesheet, Style Manager and CSS Properties keeps saying "There are no items to show for the selected documents". [image]

Does anyone know what the problem is? Shouldn't I now be able to work with my stylesheet using these two features?

The Default.aspx using the stylesheet:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without seeing the associated HTML that uses your styles.

Comment: I added a picture of Default.aspx. However, shouldnt I be able to use the visual CSS editor while editing styles.css itself?